# Bootstrap popovers without borders on the clicked element

Tags: bootstrap-popover

I want to use a Bootstrap popover on a custom element. This element is not a button, and when the user click on the element to display the popover, there is a blue border around the element because it is selected. How to remove the blue border ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following style on the element overwrite current style with shadows and borders:

```
a:focus {
     outline:none; 
     border:0px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px;
     box-shadow: 0px;
 }
```

Replace `a:focus` by `div:focus` or `.myclass:focus` depending on your element markup.